# What are entity types in regards to google cloud endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm new to google endpoints and app engine. I'm going over the tutorials on the google developers site.

What is an entity type? Specifically in regards to google cloud endpoints.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types#entity_types

Towards the bottom of the link it states.

"Entity types are those types that are available as method return types or **as the request body of an API request**. Entity types are generally used for **resources** in a REST API. Any type except a parameter or **injected type** is considered an entity type. Entity types cannot be annotated with @Named, and as an API request can only have one body, there can only be a single entity parameter per method. For example:

public Resource set(Resource resource) { … }"

1. "Entity types are those types that are available as method return types". Does this just mean an entity type is what methods return? specifically what the api methods return? (I guess that might explain the next question about the body of the API request)
2. "as the request body of an API request" does that just mean the body of a package? doesn't everything qualify as that?
3. What is a resources? is it just like a POJO or javaBean? Read it a few times but don't know exactly what it is.
4. What is an injected type?

Cheers Tony.